# Differentiability

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is a function defined from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $f$ differentiable at $x=a$ and $f(a)=0$, discuss when $|f|$ is differentiable at $a$? 
Can I say "$f$ must be not linear or constant function" Is that enough answer?

Answer (score 0):

In order to $|f|$ be differentiable at $x=a$ the following limit must exist and be finite

$$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{|f(x)-f(a)|}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a} \frac{|f(x)|}{x-a}.$$

So, what can be the value of this limit?

If $f'(a)= c>0$ then, for some $r,$ $f$ is negative in $(a-r,a)$ and positive in (a,a+r).$ Thus,

$$\lim_{x\to a^-} \frac{|f(x)|}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a^-} \frac{-f(x)}{x-a}=-c$$ and

$$\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{|f(x)|}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{-f(x)}{x-a}=c.$$ That is, $|f|$ is not differentiable at $x=a.$ In a similar way it is possible to discard $f'(a)= c<0.$ That is, it must be $f'(a)=0.$ In such a case we have

$$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{x-a}=0.$$ But then,

$$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{|f(x)-f(a)|}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a} \frac{|f(x)|}{x-a}=0.$$

That is,

$|f|$ is differentiable at $x=a$ if and only if $f'(a)=0.$

Comment: Can I take f(x)=0 ,since f(a) = 0 and derivative of f at a equal to 0.

Comment: Yes, the constant function $f(x)=0$ satisfies that $|f|$ is differentiable.

Comment: Thank you a lot . What is the best reference in real analysis.